# Create Pi image from wireless headless Pi for distribution - remove SSID and password

Tags: wifi, headless, image, wpa-supplicant

I want to create a Pi image that I can distribute to others. I have the basics down for doing this for myself, and it works. But for my own use, that fact that my WiFi SSID and password are included in the image is fine. That's not fine for distribution. I'm interacting with the source Pi in headless mode over WiFi.

- What files, in what directories, do I need to edit to remove my SSID and Password so they won't be in the image?
- Can can I do this and still access the Pi over WiFi while doing this and then restore the
  values, or will I have to connect via ethernet?

Answer (score 0):

My thanks to KLRicks over at the Raspberry Pi forum, who provided the answer:
Edit or remove /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
You will be connected to WIFI until next reboot.